# Xcode 8.0 conversion issue

Tags: swift, xcode

AS I have updated the XCode to 8, new version, the following code

```
func center(_ usePresentationLayer: Bool) -> CGPoint 
{
    if usePresentationLayer, let presentationLayer = layer.presentation() as! CALayer
    {
        return presentationLayer.position
    }
    return center
}
```

result in

```
Error -  Value of type 'CALayer' has no member 'presentation'
```

How can I fix this issue in XCode using swift 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: the question changed*

Make sure `request` is of type `URLRequest`.

Don't upload screenshots of code - please edit your post so it contains code that's searchable.

Comment: `request`? are you sure that's the question your post answers?

Comment: well, it was. but the question got changed over time. initially, there was a screenshot with this error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UfTur.png